# Using fwrite in Visual C++ 2005

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, fwrite

I'm used to using fwrite to write the contents of a buffer to a file in gcc. However, for some reason, fwrite doesn't seem to work correctly in Visual C++ 2005.

What I'm doing now is to convert a text file into binary. The program worked fine for the first 61 lines, but at the 62nd line, it inserted a 0x0d into the output binary file. Basically, it turned the original

```
12 0a 00
```

to

```
12 0d 0a 00
```

I checked the buffer, the content was correct, i.e.

```
buffer[18] = 0x12, buffer[19] = 0x0a, buffer[20] = 0x00
```

And I tried to write this buffer to file by

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, length, fout)
```

where length is the correct value of the size of the buffer content.

This happened to me once, and I had to change my code from fwrite to WriteFile for it to work correctly. Is there a reason a 0x0d is inserted into my output? Can I fix this, or do I have to try using WriteFile instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the file has been opened in text mode, so it is converting each of the newline characters it sees to a newline+carriage return sequence.

When you open your file, specify binary mode by using the **b** qualifier on the file mode:

```
FILE *pFile = fopen(szFilename, "wb");
```

In VC++, if **t** or **b** is not given in the file mode, the default translation mode is defined by the global variable `_fmode`. This may explain the difference between compilers.

You'll need to do the same when reading a binary file too. In text mode, carriage return–linefeed combinations are translated into single linefeeds on input, and linefeed characters are translated to carriage return–linefeed combinations on output.